# How to access a CardLayout variable from an outside class?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

I have two classes (lay and panelTwo). In "lay" I have my MainMethod and this is where I've put my CardLayout. What I'm trying to do is access that class within another outside class. But I can't seem to access it whilst trying to write my ActionListener:

```
 public class lay {

JFrame frame;
JPanel panelCont;
JPanel panelOne;
JButton buttonOne;
CardLayout cards;

PanelTwo panelTwo;

public lay() {
    frame = new JFrame("Start");
    panelCont = new JPanel();
    panelOne = new JPanel();
    panelTwo = new PanelTwo();
    buttonOne = new JButton("Got to two");
    cards = new CardLayout();

    panelCont.setLayout(cards);

    panelOne.add(buttonOne);
    panelOne.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    panelCont.add(panelOne, "1");
    panelCont.add(panelTwo, "2");
    cards.show(panelCont, "1");

    buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cards.show(panelCont, "2");
        }
    });

    frame.add(panelCont);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new lay();
        }
    });
}

}
```

And here is my other class where the problem is:

```
public class PanelTwo extends JPanel {

JButton buttonTwo;

public PanelTwo() {

    buttonTwo = new JButton("Go to one");

    add(buttonTwo);
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    buttonTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cards.show(panelCont, "1");
        }
    });


    }

}
```

As you can probably tell, I get errors in "cards.show(panelCont, "1")". And I do understand why that is. I just don't know what the solution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do they *need* to be in separate files? You can make `PanelTwo` an inner class of `lay` class. You're getting the error, because the tow variables are not in the scope of the `lay` class which those are members of. If you did the below, errors would go away.

```
public class lay {
   ...
   private class PanelTwo {

   }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

What you need to do using two separate class files is to create a constructor in the `PanelTwo` where you take in arguments of your `CardLayout` and the `JPanel` from the `lay` class. Then instantiate the `PanelTwo` with those two arguments.

Try this out. I passed the `CardLayout` and the `JPanel` to a constructor of `PanelTwo`. Works fine.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class lay {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panelCont;
    JPanel panelOne;
    JButton buttonOne;
    CardLayout cards;

    PanelTwo panelTwo;

    public lay() {
        frame = new JFrame("Start");
        panelCont = new JPanel();
        panelOne = new JPanel();
        cards = new CardLayout();
        panelTwo = new PanelTwo(cards, panelCont);
        buttonOne = new JButton("Got to two");


        panelCont.setLayout(cards);

        panelOne.add(buttonOne);
        panelOne.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        panelCont.add(panelOne, "1");
        panelCont.add(panelTwo, "2");
        cards.show(panelCont, "1");

        buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cards.show(panelCont, "2");
            }
        });

        frame.add(panelCont);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new lay();
            }
        });
    }

}

class PanelTwo extends JPanel {

    JButton buttonTwo;
    CardLayout layout;
    JPanel panelCont;

    public PanelTwo(final CardLayout layout, final JPanel panelCont) {
        this.layout = layout;
        this.panelCont = panelCont;
        buttonTwo = new JButton("Go to one");

        add(buttonTwo);
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        buttonTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                layout.show(panelCont, "1");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I also initialized the `CardLayout` in the `lay` constructor *before* initializing the `PanelTwo`. This avoids a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Yes, they need to be in separate files.

Comment: When I press the "Go to two" it does it correctly. But when I press the "Go to one" button I get the NullPointerException.

Comment: Read the very last part of my answer. And stare at the `lay` constructor carefully.

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you! Works perfectly! :)